# Riemann zeta conjugate extension to real plane < 1

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation

I found this function:

$$
\zeta(\alpha+i\beta)*\zeta(\alpha-i\beta)=\prod \frac{1}{1-\frac{2cos(\beta ln{p})}{p^\alpha} + \frac{1}{p^{2\alpha}}}=\Re(\zeta(\alpha+i\beta))^2 +\Im(\zeta(\alpha+i\beta))^2
$$

so its a real function with values such as $(2+i0) -> (\frac{\pi^2}{6})^2$ and so on and so forth. But I'm not too sure how to extend it because it seems like its only convergent in the region with real > 1 as usual. I don't see how to extend it. I tried alternating sign like eta but to no avail. Anybody knows how to extend it to below 1?

Thank you

Comment: the above is just $|\zeta(s)|^2$ for $\Re s >1$ so it extends the same way $\zeta$ does